# maven does not open the browser

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I am fresher to testing. I developed a maven selenium project. It shown the build failure and display `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices.`

What is the reason for that issue? Here I had attached my code.

This is my project explorer window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZwzV.png)

**SampleTest.java**

```
package com.java.maven;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SecondTest {
    WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void test()
{
    System.out.println("hai");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/driver/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");

}
}
```

**POM.xml file**
This is my pom.xml file.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SecondGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>SecondArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>SecondMaven</name>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0rc2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

   <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->

          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

**Console**
This is my console which are obtained as my output.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SecondMaven 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SecondArtifactId ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ SecondArtifactId ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SecondArtifactId ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SecondArtifactId ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ SecondArtifactId ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: E:\MavenRepository\SecondArtifactId\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.java.maven.SecondTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@1ee0005
hai
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.227 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(com.java.maven.SecondTest)  Time elapsed: 0.047 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.java.maven.SecondTest.test(SecondTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 58 more


Results :

Failed tests:   test(com.java.maven.SecondTest): org/openqa/selenium/interactions/HasInputDevices

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.273 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-18T11:26:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/138M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project SecondArtifactId: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to E:\MavenRepository\SecondArtifactId\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: can you modify your question, add the code that you have written. Add your maven console output. 

Please follow these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) while asking questions.

Comment: pArAs,Sorry for my mistake.Now i add my code and console with my question.

Comment: ok can you show me your project structure where exactly you have kept the `SampleTest` class

Comment: ya,I show you the location of the sample test class as an image.

Comment: Got it.. please move your `SampleTest` class to 'src/test/java` folder and then execute your test case.

Comment: Thanks,If i do so,it shows some errors that ,                                         Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.115 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(com.java.test.SampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.1 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/service/DriverService at com.java.test.SampleTest.test(SampleTest.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: show me your pom.xml where this dependency is mentioned.

Comment: oh sure,Now i update pom.xml and the console with it.

Comment: do one thing just add <scope>test</scope> for all the dependency you are using to run your test. It should work then.

Comment: As per your command i did,but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NoClassDefFoundError`; seems like you miss selenium-remote-driver.jar from your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

NOTE: I've added 'test' because you run your code from tests. Read more about maven scopes [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.53.0

https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/service/DriverService.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But still it appears the same error.

Comment: you get the same error after u added the following dependency? ?

Comment: ya,I got the same error.Is there anyother way  to avoid the error?

Comment: can u send your updated pom file? in addition, run mvn dependency:tree and paste the results

Comment: as mentioned by @pArAs, add <scope>test</scope> to your 'dependency', see in my answer above.

Comment: @dollydoll "accept" answer by click the V sign, (in the beginning of the answer)